# Insertar imagen en pdf con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

Tengo un PDF ya creado para el cual quiero insertar una imagen, probé con la librería de jsPDF pero solo podría crear un nuevo PDF no modifica uno ya creado, ¿alguien sabrá alguna forma de hacerlo?

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasFirma");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var doc = new jsPDF();

doc.text(20, 20, 'Hola Mensaje');
doc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"), 'PNG', 30, 30);
doc.save('test.pdf');
```

Comment: Y si agregas la imagen antes de generar el PDF?

Comment: Tengo un mi plantilla en PDF y solo le tengo que agregar la imagen que es una firma, no podria generar primero el PDF porque ya lo tengo